# Data Reader and Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

Tags: asp.net, sqldatareader

This is my code:

```
protected void logujButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user = "data source=myHostServer; database = myDataBase; user id=myLogin; password=myPassword";
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(user);
    con2.Open();

    string loguj = "select count(*) from uzytkownik where Login = '"+ logujTextBox.Text +"'";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(loguj, con2);
    int wartosc = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    con2.Close();

    if (wartosc == 1)
    {
        con2.Open();
        SqlCommand pobierzHaslo = new SqlCommand("select Haslo from uzytkownik where Login = '" + logujTextBox.Text + "'", con2);
        SqlDataReader rdr = pobierzHaslo.ExecuteReader();
        string haslo = rdr["Haslo"].ToString();
        if (haslo == hasloTextBox.Text)
        {
            errorLabel.Text = "Prawidlowe Haslo !";
        }
        else
        {
            errorLabel.Text = "Zle haslo !";
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        errorLabel.Text = "Taki uzytkownik nie istnieje !";
    }
}
```

When I press button, this error is appearing: "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present". Could You tell me, where i made mistake ?. Thanks for advise !

Comment: Debug your code and tell us which line this is happening on.

Comment: There is a problem with this line "string haslo = rdr["Haslo"].ToString();"

Comment: Please read about [parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).  Your current methodology is susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't read anything from the reader yet.  You have to call the Read() method:

```
 SqlDataReader rdr = pobierzHaslo.ExecuteReader();
 if (rdr.Read())
 {
        string haslo = rdr["Haslo"].ToString();
        ....
 }
```

Comment: Thank You !. Now it's working, but there is some bug that i don't understand. Reader is receiving value from database corectly, but prgoram is executing code in "else" statement, not in "if". Why is that ?. I know that value from redader is corectly beacause in "else statemnet" i changed  'errorLabel.Text = "Zle haslo !";' into 'errorLabel.Text = haslo;'.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution. The problem was with database. I changed the column data type and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SSMS, run the query directly in a query window and make sure that you get data back.  Your query may be bad.  It is most likely an error from the ExecuteReader method of your SqlDataReader, based on the text of the error message.